# Language problem: what is tetra?

Tags: fish, aquarium, terminology

I hope the question is valid for this group. Unfortunately, I am not English native speaker.

If someone refers to "tetra" what species do they have in mind?

[Image search on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=tetra&tbm=isch) gives many different results, also the list on ["tetra" article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetra) from Wikipedia.

*I'm asking because in [that question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/6114/207) it is not said (however the species name is not important in the question)*

Answer (score 4):

Most commonly, The Neon Tetra (Paracheirodon innesi) . These are small freshwater fish, very common in aquariums; inexpensive, attractive, and fairly easy to care for.